# Kotlin KClass instance inside extension function

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-function

I need to access to class type inside a generic extension function. For example, if I want to make an extension function to return a collections of the members of the type I am extending, I would do:

```
fun <T> T.getMembers() =
       this::class.memberProperties
```

The problem is that I cannot do this::class nor T::class inside the function. Is there any way to access to the class type of a generic type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you wouldn't use `::` to get the class from `this`, because `this` references an instance, not a type. Generally you would get the class from `this` with `this.javaClass.kotlin`

T references a type, so generally you would reference the KClass with `T::class`.

However, in your specific code snippet neither of these will work without some additional changes.

Since generic type `T` is not constrained to `Any`, you cannot access the javaClass field. To add the constrain, use:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> T.getMembers() =
   this::class.memberProperties
```

Since generic type is not reified, you cannot use `T::class`. To reify T, use:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.getMembers() =
   T::class.memberProperties
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters

Comment: Thanks you very much!!

Comment: Making `T` a child of `Any` solved my (almost entirely unrelated) issue -- thank you!

Comment: This results in the warning `Receiver parameter is never used`. Any idea on how to surpress/avoid that?

Comment: @Anigif The first code block in my answer won't have this issue. The second example was an illustration of how the OP could still use the :: operator to get the class from the reified type, but in practice the first code block is probably a better choice. The behavior is slightly different, though. The first code block gets the members of the instance's runtime type, whereas the second code block gets the members of the receiver's compile-time type (e.g. a variable's declared type).